How to get the path of the print history
how do I get access to the print history using my code, I know how to do this in 2 ways, both manually and they are not on this PC folder, so how do I get the print history, using Node.js
the first:
on windows 11 settings on (Bluetooth& devices > Printers& scanners > "printerName" > open print queue)
the second:
Event Viewer > Application and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > PrintService
The reason for that is to get copies of what the device will print.
thanks for helping
